# How to use a variable as string or object in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a variable that can either be a string or object like this:

```
value?: string | { name: string, type: string }
```

Trying something below but I get a compile error:

```
console.log(value?.name || value)
console.log(value?.type)
```

How can use this variable if it can be either type?

Comment: 1st you use `value` and in second console you are using  `track`?

Comment: whoops thank you, issue remains just a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have two options

```
console.log(typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name);
```

But as you used ?: in definition for this value (allowing undefined) and as i think that console is only for simple example there

```
if (value === undefined) {
} else if (typeof value === 'string') {
} else {
}
```

Would be best.

This issue you found is mostly done because both values for `value` variable are objects and ts saw that the types are not compatible and asks you to narrow them by hand

Answer (score 4):

In this case you can do:

```js
console.log(typeof value === 'string' ? value : value?.name)
```

Typescript can narrow the type using type-guards, see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) for more details.